# SQL Server tells me these polygons intersect but why?

Tags: sql-server, geo

According to SQL Server these two polygons intersect ... can anyone tell me why?
If I render the WKT they appear not to.

```
declare @polygon1 geography = geography::Parse('POINT(-2.0937529 57.14989)').STBuffer(3000)
declare @polygon2 geography = geography::Parse('POLYGON ((-0.582275 51.770529,  0.601501 51.739921,  0.4422 51.264558,  -0.741577 51.266276,  -0.582275 51.770529))');

-- Should not intersect?
select @polygon2.STIntersection(@polygon1).ToString()
```

Thanks

Comment: i'm guessing the problem is that coords are flipped. is the polygon suppose to go near africa or england?

Comment: The accepted answer points you to the problem (often called a "ring orientation" issue). One heuristic that I use to detect those is using the [`EnvelopeAngle()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/envelopeangle-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-ver16) function. If that returns value close to 180, then the given polygon likely has the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinates in your [polygon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/polygon?view=sql-server-ver16) seem to be in the wrong order:

> The interior of the polygon in an ellipsoidal system is defined by the
> "left-hand rule": if you imagine yourself walking along the ring of a
> geography Polygon, following the points in the order in which they are
> listed, the area on the left is being treated as the interior of the
> Polygon, and the area on the right as the exterior of the Polygon.

Try this:

```
declare @polygon1 geography = geography::Parse('POINT(-2.0937529 57.14989)').STBuffer(3000)
declare @polygon2 geography = geography::Parse('POLYGON ((-0.582275 51.770529,  -0.741577 51.266276,  0.4422 51.264558,   0.601501 51.739921, -0.582275 51.770529))');

 --Should not intersect?
select @polygon2.STIntersection(@polygon1).ToString()
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!

I have to say I find the format a little confusing since counter clockwise or clockwise specification of points does not seem to be interpreted consistently when used to render, vs passed as  an argument to the intersection function: 


If I plot  (20 30, 35 35, 30 20, 20 30) alone:

POLYGON ((20 30, 35 35, 30 20, 20 30))
Then one side is shaded

POLYGON ((35 10, 45 45, 15 40, 10 20, 35 10), (20 30, 35 35, 30 20, 20 30))
Its the other!